# Sending form input to a public database?

Tags: database, forms, table

I am looking for a code that will send input from a form to a database or table. For example, there would be a form:

```
<input type='text' name='name'>
```

And then a table:

```
<td>(what they entered for 'name')<td>
```

So basically the submitted form could be seen by anyone viewing the table or database. Please try to dumb down your answer for me, I'm still learning.

Comment: Normally these kinds of questions are migrated to StackOverflow. But due to its low quality nature they will close it as soon as they receive it so I am just going to close it here.